# Why the directives 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path' & 'Loaded Configuration File' from o/p of phpinfo() are showing entirely different locations?

Tags: php, windows, ini, php-ini, mod-php

I'm using a machine running on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**

I've installed **PHP 7.2.9** and **Apache/2.4.34 (Win32)** using the latest version of **XAMPP** installer tool on this machine.

PHP is installed as an Apache SAPI.

I checked the output of `phpinfo()` in my web browser and I got some strange results for couple of properties as follows :

The two locations shown by two co-related attributes are entirely different as follows :

> **Configuration File (php.ini) Path**     C:\WINDOWS
>
> **Loaded Configuration File**             C:\xampp\php\php.ini

I've made sure by that the loaded configuration file(php.ini) is located at location **C:\xampp\php\php.ini** only.

Then, why the property **'Configuration File (php.ini) Path'** isn't containing the path of the folder that contains **php.ini** configuration file?

Why the property **'Configuration File (php.ini) Path'** doesn't show the folder path as **C:\xampp\php**